# How do I get the values of multiple text fields on submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I am trying to get the values that are currently in various text fields. I have lots of text fields on my page, and they are managed using a unified state/handler (please see code below).

I have the submit button firing properly, but I don't know what to put in there in order to get the values from the text fields.

**Problem:**

How do I properly set this up so that the submit function obtains the current values in each text field?

**My Code:**

```
function handleSubmit() {
  // HOW DO I GET THE VALUES?
  console.log('CURRENT VALUE OF firstItem')
  console.log('CURRENT VALUE OF secondItem')
}

const [textFields, setTextFields] = useState({
  firstItem: "",
  secondItem: ""
});

const handleChangeTextField = (type) => (value) => {
  setTextFields((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [type]: value
  }));
};

<TextField
  id="firstItem"
  variant="filled"
  value={textFields.firstItem}
  onChange={handleChangeTextField("firstItem")}
/>
<TextField
  id="secondItem"
  variant="filled"
  value={textFields.secondItem}
  onChange={handleChangeTextField("secondItem")}
/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textfield values are stored in state, so you would access them via the `textFields` state variable.

```
function handleSubmit() {
  console.log('CURRENT VALUE OF firstItem', textFields.firstItem);
  console.log('CURRENT VALUE OF secondItem', textFields.secondItem);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, any ideas why there would be error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: textFields is not defined`?

Comment: Got it - I was using a handleSubmit function that existed outside of the main function. Thanks!